# How to make a python script to fetch columns data in a text file?

Tags: python

I have a scenario where the data is like below in a text file:

```
first_id;"second_id";"name";"performer";"criteria"
12345;"13254";"abc";"def";"criteria_1"
65432;"13254";"abc";"ghi";"criteria_1"
24561;"13254";"abc";"pqr";"criteria_2"
24571;"13254";"abc";"jkl";"criteria_2"

first_id;"second_id";"name";"performer";"criteria"
12345;"78452";"mno";"xyz";"criteria_1"
24561;"78452";"mno";"tuv";"criteria_2"

so on..
```

Note: The name column value remains same for each result fetched, but the performer varies for each row and has criteria set. The second_id column values are same for each result fetched.

For the above data, I need to capture the name and performer and have to move them to excel sheet as comma separated value like below output. The author value is based on name column defined above, approver values are based on criteria_1 and reviewer values are based on criteria_2.

```
**author|   approver|    reviewer** --> columns in excel
   abc  |   def, ghi|    pqr, jkl   --> values corresponding to their columns
```

See the below picture for my expected output. The author is of "name" field defined above. approver field is determined based on "criteria" - criteria_1, reviewer field is determined based on "criteria" - criteria_2.

[picture for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvzyv.png)

Here, I'm requesting to how to make a script in python to get the above output? Let me know for any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `pandas` would be a good solution if I understand the problem you're having. Taking the first set of input data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# the example data
data  = io.StringIO('''first_id;"second_id";"name";"performer";"criteria"
12345;"13254";"abc";"def";"criteria_1"
65432;"13254";"abc";"ghi";"criteria_1"
24561;"13254";"abc";"pqr";"criteria_2"
24571;"13254";"abc";"jkl";"criteria_2"''')

# reading the IO like a file with a semi-colon separator
pd.read_csv(data, sep = ";")
```

will give output like

```
   first_id  second_id name performer    criteria
0     12345      13254  abc       def  criteria_1
1     65432      13254  abc       ghi  criteria_1
2     24561      13254  abc       pqr  criteria_2
3     24571      13254  abc       jkl  criteria_2
```

you can then easily export the data back to Excel with:

```
df.to_excel('INSERT FILE PATH HERE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

#Import the text file
df=pd.read_csv('INSERT FILE PATH HERE',sep=';')

#Export the formatted results to Excel
df.to_excel('INSERT FILE PATH HERE')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. But my expected answer is not this. How do I concatenate the performer column by comma before saving to Excel based on the criteria that I have mentioned for each result?

Comment: @Srivastava Please clarify your question further if we haven't been able to address it. It is not very clear what you mean.

Comment: @notlink I have added picture for my expected output. Please can you refer that and help me and I have added additional info as "The author is of "name" field defined above. approver field is determined based on "criteria" - criteria_1, reviewer field is determined based on "criteria" - criteria_2."

Comment: @Srivastava just to be clear -- from your picture it looks like you eventually want to collapse the `approver` and `reviewer` columns based on the values in `second_id`. Is that correct?

Comment: @notlink Sorry, I didn't get your point, anyway I want to clarify, the concatenation of approver and reviewer column values should happen only based on criteria column. In the input, for example, in the performer column (consider) we have values as def, ghi in which the criteria is criteria_1 for both correspondingly. So in output, they should they be concatenated as def, ghi for criteria_1 and similarly for criteria_2. Yes, the second_id remains same for each result. Please let me know if it's clear.